# Seaborn FacetGrid keyerror

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, seaborn, facet-grid

My pandas dataframe looks like this

```
hours Record Result
04      1     Pass
12      2     Fail
04      3     Good
15      4     Warning
```

I have 500 rows in my dataframe.I want to plot hours on x axis with the number of records on y axis faceted by result.I need 4 graphs each for pass,fail,good and warning condition.I need to find for each hours how many records fall in each result category.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(batch_3, row=batch_3['hours'], col=batch_3['Result'], hue=batch_3['Result'])
g.map(plt.plot, 'Stat')
```

I am getting the following error

```
KeyError:'WARNING' 'WARNING' 'GOOD' 'GOOD' 'WARNING' 'WARNING',.....] not in index"
```

Comment: See [mcve] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). You are completely ignoring the `FacetGrid` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `KeyError` is that you should pass the column name as a string to the `FacetGrid` parameters, rather than passing the actual column as a series. For example, this would work

```
sns.FacetGrid(batch_3, row='hours', hue='Result')
```

but this would not

```
sns.FacetGrid(batch_3, row=batch_3['hours'], hue=batch_3['Result'])
```